# v-on:click expects a function value, got undefined

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-router, vue-component

I'm trying to learn vuejs, currently trying to react to a button press, but the v-on:click directive doesn't find (apparently) the method I added to the component.

Here's my component:

```
<template>
    <!-- super big form ... -->      
            <div class="card-content">     
            <div class="card-action">
                <a class="waves-effect waves-light btn blue darken-4" v-on:click="createOrganization">Guardar</a>
                <a class="waves-effect waves-light btn red darken-4">Limpiar</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    var Vue = require('vue');

    module.exports.addOrganization = new Vue({
        name: 'addOrganization',
        methods: {
            createOrganization: function(event){
                event.preventDefault();
                alert("0");
            }
        }
    });
</script>
```

This is the parent component

```
<template>  
    <div id="navbar">
        <navbar></navbar>
    </div>
        <router-view></router-view>
</template>

<script>
    var nav = require('./src/components/navbar.vue');
    module.exports = {
        data () {
            return {
                var: "hi",
            }
        },
        components: {
            'navbar': nav
        }
    }
</script>
```

And here's the main file

```
var VueRouter = require('vue-router');
var addOrg = require('./src/components/addOrganization.vue');
var Vue = require('vue'); 
var App = require('./App.vue');
var VueResource = require('vue-resource');

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('select').material_select();

    var d = new Date();
    d.setFullYear( d.getFullYear() - 100 );
    $('.datepicker').pickadate(
    {
        selectMonths: true,
        selectYears: d,
        max: new Date()
    })
});

Vue.use(VueResource);
Vue.use(VueRouter);

new Vue({
  el: 'body',
  components: {
    app: App
  },
})

var router = new VueRouter();

router.map({
    '/': {
        name: 'addOrganization',
        component: addOrg
    }
})  

router.start(App, '#brightcrest');
```

And the warning I'm getting

```
vue.common.js:1019[Vue warn]: v-on:click="createOrganization" expects a function value, got undefined
```

Then, the button doesn't do anything, it doesn't show any errors or anything.

Comment: please mark your answer as correct, so other people will know it without coming at this page.

Comment: Yeah, I've been trying to :( stack overflow says I have to wait 2 days, so I'm on that. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out, apparently I didn't have to use a new Vue object because vueify wraps it up when you're using single file components, so apparently the function was living in the parent component and not in the actual component.

Here's the script part, the only thing I changed:

```
<script>
    module.exports = {
        name: 'addOrganization',
        methods: {
            createOrganization: function(event){
                event.preventDefault();
                alert("0");
            }
        }
    };
</script>
```